# WordPress Admin back-end - advanced options page?

Tags: admin, options

Am I losing my mind? I seem to recall that somewhere in the Admin back-end there was a page that basically listed out all the fields within wp_options. Does this ring a bell to anyone else? I thought maybe it was a MU thing but it's not there either. At one point I seem to recall running into a page where you could edit the options directly (without using a DB client). No big deal if there isn't but I swear I've seen such a beast, and I don't think it was through a plugin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Adds 'ALL' options page - only accessible for admins and custom roles that have the 'manage_options' capability.
function wpse31956_all_settings_page() 
{
    add_options_page( __('All'), __('All'), 'manage_options', 'options.php' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse31956_all_settings_page' );
```

Note: As I just saw that me an @ChipBennet posted at nearly the same time: The answer is the same.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/options.php
```

Which lists *all* of the site's options.

Comment: Was this available in the sidebar navigation at some point and was recently removed? I doubt I would have randomly typed that URI in...

Comment: Not as far as I know; but it's a well-known (and oft-mentioned) "power trick" to append `options.php` to the end of the `/wp-admin/` URL.